# openvpn client cant reach external internet

Tags: iptables, openvpn

Setting up an openvpn server with tls auth and ip forwarding.

I could connect to the vpn server just fine, but couldn't reach any outside connections

I could not successfully ping `8.8.8.8` the google dns service

but I knew I could connect to the vpn server:

```
tcpdump -i tun0
```

where `tun0` is my vpn interface
and could see packets comming in from my client.
But the problem was that my iptables chain was reversed

here is my old iptables

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 2345 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2345 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

You can see that this is backwards

```
-A FORWARD -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

before any forwarded packet is accepted. it is dropped immediately
simply reversing it fixed the issue

```
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DROP
```

once I fixed it everything else worked just fine.
The only problem is that I feel a little silly

Comment: Can you post the full output of `iptables-save`?

Comment: @Isaac Freeman sure, edited into the post

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there would be something else in the iptables causing problems, but it's pretty vanilla. Hopefully someone else will be able to help. :}

Comment: I _think_ what you want is to use either the PREROUTING table or the FORWARD table instead of POSTROUTING, but I'm not positive. Try tinkering with those to see if you get anywhere. There's a pretty detailed guide on iptables routing [here](http://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/chunkyhtml/c962.html).

Comment: If you solved the problem, please post an Answer. Questions are for Questions.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried accessing a website/server via ip to exclude DNS as a error source?
If that works try adding `push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"` to your server.conf
.This pushes the Google-DNS server to the client, helping to resolve the adresses

Comment: else this is my iptables
[pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/dGdQUwWK)

Comment: yeah,  from my client i cant ping  any ip other than the vpn server